# Best practice for working with long texts in ms-access

Tags: ms-access, textbox, memo, longtext

I would be very thankful if somebody resolves my problem.
I'm new in working with Ms Access and I still gain experience on its basic functionality.

I have a table MyItems. 2 of its fields are: ItemCode and ItemName. ItemName is a very long text (Memo type). I have also a query and a form with many fields. The form's record source also consists of many fields. All these things (associated with 1 field) have the same or similar names so I can't differentiate them quite well.

What I want is when I set the value of ItemCode (in a not bound Combobox or Listbox with name ItemCode) the value of ItemName to be displayed in a control - maybe TextBox.

I can display its value in a ListBox (by sql query in its row source), I have no problems with this, I have no problems with managing events, but the text is very long and is cut. I understood that unfortunately ListBoxes don't have multiline property. So maybe the most appropriate control to deal with is a TextBox. And maybe the most appropriate way to display the value is using DLookUp function in the TextBox's control source. But in this sea of items with similar or the same names I just can't deal with its syntax, I was trying again and again for a very long time. So I have 2 questions:

1. Are the TextBox control and DLookUp function in its control source the best way to extract long texts from a table without binding or there are more suitable controls (which directly work with sql query)?
2. What is the right syntax of DLookUp? - where exactly are there ' ', " ", [ ], .Value, =, &, where must I write the path to the table or the form and where it would be mistake? If I just write [ItemCode] what it would be associated with - the form record source, the table, the form control or anything else? I would be grateful if someone writes the correct syntax for my case or if he shares a link with plenty of examples for using DLookUp. Those that I found didn't satisfy me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Either a bound control, or an unbound one. If unbound, you need to load the text with VBA code or with `DLookup` in the control source. There are no other options.
   Personally I'd rather use the `AfterUpdate` event of `ItemCode`, and call `DLookup` there, but that's a matter of preference.
  2.

It's not that complicated. You basically have the SELECT, FROM, WHERE parts of an SQL query in the 3 arguments. `[]` are needed for all identifiers containing spaces or other special characters, and when refering to form controls.

```
=DLookup("ItemName", "[my Table]", "ItemCode = '" & [ItemCode] & "'")
```

The single quotes `''` are needed if `ItemCode` is text, not when it is a number.

You could also use doubled (escaped) double quotes, but that is much less readable.

```
=DLookup("ItemName", "[my Table]", "ItemCode = """ & [ItemCode] & """")
```

Now where does `[ItemCode]` come from?

- Access first looks for a **control** on the form with the name `ItemCode`.
- If there isn't one, it looks for a field `ItemCode` in the form's **RecordSource**.

These are the only ways `[ItemCode]` can be evaluated. To avoid confusion, it is recommended to name bound controls with the same name as their source field.

The syntax above is only valid if everything is on the same form. If `[ItemCode]` is on a different form, or you refer to it from a query, you use

```
=DLookup("ItemName", "[my Table]", "ItemCode = '" & Forms![my Form]![ItemCode] & "'")
```

For more complicated cases with subforms, see [Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

And to use it in VBA (in `ItemCode_AfterUpdate`):

```
Me!ItemName = DLookup("ItemName", "[my Table]", "ItemCode = '" & Me![ItemCode] & "'")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now things are much clearer and understandable. The code worked. I haven't tried with " ' ". However one thing I should correct, maybe because of ms-access version, my defaults or whether using vba/design mode - the separator in the function is ";" - not ","

Comment: @Peter: Yes, e.g. in German Access, the argument separator is ; instead of , when using functions in Forms or Queries. Not in VBA, though.